# Infinite sum with factorial

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am learning about Poisson Random Variable and came across a problem with this infinite sum:

$\sum^{∞}_{n=2}\frac{e^{-2}(2)^i}{i!}$

The first step I do is move the constant $e^{-2}$ out.

$e^{-2} * (\sum^{∞}_{n=2}\frac{(2)^i}{i!})$

But I don't know what is the next step after this, I am trying to use this formula: $\frac{a}{1-r}$

I looked through my notes from class, but I can only find basic example that cover $\sum^{∞}_{n=1} 2x$. In the this case, what would be the ratio?

Comment: Hint: What is the Taylor series for the exponential function?

Comment: HINT: $$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^i}{i!} = e^x$$

Comment: Shouldn't the $n$ in the index of the sum be an $i$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the series expansion for the exponential function, 
$$e^{x} = \sum_{r=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^{r}}{r!},$$
then by subtracting the first two terms from both sides:
$$\sum_{r=2}^{\infty} \frac{x^{r}}{r!} = e^{x} - 1 - x.$$

Now, 
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-2} \, 2^{n}}{n!} &= e^{-2} \, \left(e^{2} - 1 - 2 \right) \\
&= 1 - 3 \, e^{-2}.
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

It will certainly help to know that
$$ e^x=\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{x^i}{i!}$$

Just fill in $x=2$ and work from there!

The equality I use is called the [taylor series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) at $0$ or the maclaurin series of $e^x$. It's not hard to derive.